# Jenkins Publish Over SSh pipeline parameterized

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am using Publish over SSH plugin in Jenkins to deploy the jar file which is created from the build process. I have created a pipeline like this

```
node {
 {
        stage('Checkout') {
            git([url: '.............', branch: 'myBranch', credentialsId: 'mycredentials'])
        }
        stage('Build') {
            script{
                sh 'chmod a+x mvnw'
                sh './mvnw clean package'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy to Server'){
            def pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
            script {
                sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: 'server-instance1',
                        transfers: [sshTransfer(cleanRemote:true,
                                sourceFiles: "target/${env.PROJECT_NAME}-${pom.version}.jar",
                                removePrefix: "target",
                                remoteDirectory: "${env.PROJECT_NAME}",
                                execCommand: "mv ${env.PROJECT_NAME}/${env.PROJECT_NAME}-${pom.version}.jar ${env.PROJECT_NAME}/${env.PROJECT_NAME}.jar"),
                                    sshTransfer(
                                            execCommand: "/etc/init.d/${env.PROJECT_NAME} restart -Dspring.profiles.active=${PROFILE}"
                                    )
                        ])
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works. I have a SSH Server configured under Manage Jenkins >> Configure System >> Publish Over SSH.

Now I want to deploy on multiple servers. Lets say I create multiple ssh configurations by name server-instance1, server-instance2. How do I make this Jenkins job parameterized ? I tried with checking the checkbox and selecting a Choice Parameter. But I am not able to figure out how to make the values for this dropdown come from the SSH server list(instead of hardcoding)

I tried few things as mentioned here([How to Control Parametrized publishing in Jenkins using Publish over SSH plugin's Label field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411489/how-to-control-parametrized-publishing-in-jenkins-using-publish-over-ssh-plugin)). Unfortunately none of the articles talks about doing this from a pipeline.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select the SSH server name dynamically, you can use the [Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extended-choice-parameter/) plugin which allows you to execute groovy code that will create the options for the parameter.
In the plugin you can use the following code to get the values:

```groovy
import jenkins.model.*
def publish_ssh = Jenkins.instance.getDescriptor("jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPublisherPlugin")

configurations = publish_ssh.getHostConfigurations() // get all server configurations
return configurations.collect { it.name } // return the list of all servers
```

To configure this parameter in you pipeline you can use the following code for scripted pipeline:

```groovy
properties([
      parameters([
            extendedChoice(name: 'SERVER', type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Server for publishing', visibleItemCount: 10, 
            groovyScript: '''
                import jenkins.model.*
                def publish_ssh = Jenkins.instance.getDescriptor("jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPublisherPlugin")
                return publish_ssh.getHostConfigurations() .collect { it.name }
            ''')
      ])
])
```

Or the following code for declarative pipeline:

```groovy
pipeline {
     agent any
     parameters {
          extendedChoice(name: 'SERVER', type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Server for publishing', visibleItemCount: 10,
               groovyScript: '''
               import jenkins.model.*
               def publish_ssh = Jenkins.instance.getDescriptor("jenkins.plugins.publish_over_ssh.BapSshPublisherPlugin")
               return publish_ssh.getHostConfigurations() .collect { it.name }
          ''')
     }
     ...
}
```

Once the parameter is defined just use it in your `sshPublisher` step:

```
sshPublisher(publishers: [sshPublisherDesc(configName: SERVER, transfers: ...
```

Another option you can have when using the Extended Choice Parameter is to configure it as Multi-Select instead of Single-Select so a user can then select multiple severs, and you can use the [parallel](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#parallel-execute-in-parallel) option to publish over all selected servers in parallel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked like a peach. Just a follow up question. Is it possible to create SSH server(Under Publish over SSH section) via REST API?  This way I can automate the whole process whenever I have a new instance created.

Comment: I don't think there is an API call for this (or any plugin configuration), however you can take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085710/programmatically-getting-jenkins-configuration-for-a-plugin) it describes how to use the groovy API to create the hosts via code, you may use it in a separate job to automated the process by triggering that job via an API call with all relevant parameters for the host - thus creating an API for adding new servers.

Comment: how do i set the defaultvalue for this dropdown. Because, currently, the build fails, when it is triggered automatically when there is a push to the branch. I tried setting it like this.  defaultValue: 'someconfig' but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: The following should work for a constant value: `extendedChoice(defaultValue: 'YOUR_VALUE', name: 'SERVER', type: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT', description: 'Server for publishing', visibleItemCount: 10, groovyScript: ...)` , for a script use `defaultGroovyScript` instead.